# Subdomains on Windows Server - nslookup works, ping only with FQDN

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

I have a Windows Server machine with DNS set up in the following way:

```
Zone: home.local
Domain: apache
    A  (same as parent)   192.168.2.4
    A   xml               192.168.2.4
```

I want to be able to connect to 'apache' and 'xml.apache', and be taken to the same address - however this isn't working. On both the server and another machine, I get the following:

```
> nslookup apache
Server: UnKnown
Address: 192.168.2.2

Server: apache.home.local
Address: 192.168.2.4


> nslookup xml.apache
Server: UnKnown
Address: 192.168.2.2

Server: apache.home.local
Address: 192.168.2.4
```

The only difference being the first result is localhost & loopback address on the dns server. Pings do this:

```
> ping apache
Reply from 192.168.2.4

> ping xml.apache
Could not find host.

> ping xml.apache.home.local
Reply from 192.168.2.4
```

I have tried `/flushdns` and `net stop dnscache` but neither worked. There is nothing untoward in my hosts file.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to use the FQDN, which would be xml.apache.home.local.

Comment: To add, you could change your search suffix (or add a 2nd one) as "apache.home.local" if you want to ping "xml" but pinging "xml.apache" won't work.